# Android RelativeLayout one after another in new line

Tags: android

This is my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/button_background_dark_default"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="222"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:text="222ssss"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

now I want to repeat this steps but one after another, so in new line. how can achieve this?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+android:id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="222"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+android:id/summary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:text="222ssss"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
```

everytime is in the same line, not in new line. Thx

Comment: do you want to repeat the textview one after another or the relativelayout?

Comment: Just copy paste complete relative layout inside the root container.

Comment: @senzacionale .  Very unclear question.. Need proper clarity of what exactly you want.. Post what u expect and what you are getting currently

Comment: He expects to have a list of title/summary pairs. But he doesn't know each id must be unique, i.e. the title and summary id's must not repeat, unless he uses a ListView. Otherwise he will have to create the list in a hardcoded way, with "@+id/title1" "@+id/summary1" "@+id/title2" "@+id/summary2" etc. which is not a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this is what you are expecting. I have used vertical orientation for linear layout.

[Just copy paste complete relative layout inside the root container Linear Layout]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="222"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="222ssss"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="222"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="222ssss"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="222"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="222ssss"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="222"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="222ssss"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="222"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="222ssss"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to put relative layouts one below each other you can try to set the orientation of your linear layout to vertical `android:orientation="vertical"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeat the layout then you can use a `listview` and then put your data accordingly.